# Ionic 3 formarray validate dynamic radio button groups

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to validate radio button group that are dynamically created from a object of arrays and i want it to be validated in the form i have posted a questions seeking answer and i was not clarified and did some research again and found this article followed its trail and found formArrayName but am unable to achieve the validation

```
<form[formGroup]="form">
  <ion-select formControlName="type">
    <ion-option value="1">Full Time</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="2">Part Time</ion-option>
  </ion-select>

  <div formArrayName="employee_details">
    <ion-row class="rows" *ngFor="let employee of employee;  let rowIndex = index">
      <ion-col text-center="text-center" col-6="col-6">
        [ {{employee.id}} ]
        <br> {{employee.name}}
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col class="rows last" col-6="col-6">
        <ion-list class="row" no-lines="no-lines" radio-group="radio-group">
          <ion-item col-4="col-4">
            <ion-radio class="radio " mode="md" value="Paid"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item col-4="col-4">
            <ion-radio class="radio " mode="md" value="Unpaid"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>

        </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </div>

</form>
```

JS

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl,FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms ';

class type {
  public name: string;
  public id: string;
}
...
class employee {
  public name: string;
  public id: string;
}
...
employee: employee = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "emp1"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "emp2"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "emp3"
}];
form: FormGroup;

this.form = new FormGroup({
  'type': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  'employee_details': new FormArray([])
});
Object.keys(this.employee).forEach(function(key, index) {
  console.log(key);
  // problem is here 
  const control = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
  ( < FormArray > this.form.get('employee_details')).push(control);

});
```

Comment: I didn't quite get what you're trying to achieve here. Could you please explain what is it?

Comment: radio button group dynamically it is generated i want it to be verified at the form submittion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not formArray, but it will definitely helps you**..

**.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<ion-row class="rows" *ngFor="let detail of details; let i = index">
    <ion-col text-center="text-center" col-6="col-6">
        {{your_data}}
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col class="rows last" col-6="col-6">
        <ion-list class="row" no-lines="no-lines" radio-group="radio-group" formControlName="action{{i}}">
            <ion-item col-4>
                <ion-radio class="radio true" mode="md" value="true"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item col-4>
                <ion-radio class="radio false" mode="md" value="false"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item col-4>
                <ion-radio class="radio " mode="md" value="not sure"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<button ion-button (click)="submit()" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**.ts**
    Add this code where you get data.

```
let i;
for(i in this.details){
  this.form.setControl('action'+i, new FormControl('', Validators.required));
}
```

variable 'i' just used to produce 0,1,2,3 to add with control name. you can use your way to do this but loop is required.

Comment: just the small change i add null instead of ''

Comment: i bro there is a slight issue with the above as i absorbed  today say first time that setControl is loaded every thing is fine when you change and load back then there is a problem as it creates another set of control

Comment: Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'action0'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031872/ionic-set-control-form-builder-dynamic-form-control-name-binding

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing what you're doing right now, you can simply `map` through the array and then for each element, just create a `FormControl`

Try this:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  type: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  employee_details: new FormArray([this.employee.map(emp => new FormControl(null, Validators.required))])
});
```

Comment: can you please explain me with the name variable iam a bit confused with maping it with html

Comment: thanks for the update am checking do i have to add this in the html `[formControlName]="employee.id"`

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: thanks for your help i have a question like this.fom is loaded on constructor on load and the array is loaded on select change and it is generated also at that time only will it work?

Comment: @Shaik, if the array is generated at select change, then it won't work as the template will get rendered even before that. How exactly will you receive the options to be changed in the first place.

Comment: thats what i found this article that was doing the same with textbox i tried to do with radio button group on click that dint work `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031872/ionic-set-control-form-builder-dynamic-form-control-name-binding