# Ionic set control form builder dynamic form control name binding

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to create a radio button group with different form group name and create a control

my scenario is when i change a select it loads ajax that loads values or to say creates dynamic set of radio button groups

here every thing is fine when select changes groups are loaded and all but the problem occurs when i re change the select say by miss i selected a option based on that the radio button group was created and when i change back to the current one

I assume the controller is duplicating or not creating it gives me the error  says

`Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'action0'`

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<ion-row class="rows" *ngFor="let detail of details; let i = index">
    <ion-col text-center="text-center" col-6="col-6">
        {{your_data}}
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col class="rows last" col-6="col-6">
        <ion-list class="row" no-lines="no-lines" radio-group="radio-group" formControlName="action{{i}}">
            <ion-item col-4>
                <ion-radio class="radio true" mode="md" value="true"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item col-4>
                <ion-radio class="radio false" mode="md" value="false"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item col-4>
                <ion-radio class="radio " mode="md" value="not sure"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<button ion-button (click)="submit()" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

.ts where the select is changing after success of the response i have placed this code

```
let i;
for(i in this.details){
  this.form.setControl('action'+i, new FormControl(null, Validators.required));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://masteringionic.com/blog/2018-02-06-dynamically-add-and-remove-form-input-fields-with-ionic/) it was dynamically creating form elements and when changed that was still present in the form and was not removed when second time select was changed

Just drop a comment i vl help if you are facing the same issue